# (Java) Key wrapping with Triple Data Encryption Algorithm (TDEA) for Known Answer Test (KAT)

Tags: java, encryption, key, des

I'm working on a Known Answer Test for key wrapping and I'm stucking in finding the correct algorithm or implementation.
As described in the "official" test (https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/mac/KWVS.pdf)
I'd like to use  the Triple Data Encryption Algorithm (TDEA) so I'm working with an official testvector from NIST
(get the test vector set here: https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/mac/kwtestvectors.zip)
in the file "TKW_AE.txt", where K is the key, P is the key to wrap ("Plaintext") and C is the encrypted/wrapped ciphertext ("output"):

```
[PLAINTEXT LENGTH = 64]
COUNT = 0
K = 12b84c663120c196f8fc17428bc86a110d92cc7c4d3cb695
P = ef7da3da918d0679
C = 7a72bbca3aa323aa1ac231ba
```

My implementation seem to work as it wrapps the plaintext (key to wrap) and it unwrapps the ciphertext to the original key, but when running the
test with the same key ("K") and plaintext ("P") I'm getting different results on the ciphertext, thats because of a random IV that is used for the algorithm "DESedeWrap".

My question: **how can I setup the wrapping/unwrapping cipher to be conform with the "official" test vector result (in my example I need an output of "7a72bbca3aa323aa1ac231ba" for the ciphertext ("C)".**

This is one result:

```
TDEA KeyWrapping with Java version: 11.0.6+8-b520.43
pt        : ef7da3da918d0679
ctExpected: 7a72bbca3aa323aa1ac231ba
ct JCE    : 77d34a462f7e1fc628692ef05be251b4d8838510fe3d019b
dt JCE    : ef7da3da918d0679
ct JCE 2  : 23aa07d07bd21c3aaf6e23cbbf00cf2b3c2d140b4668f7ec
dt JCE 2  : ef7da3da918d0679
```

Sourcecode:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class KeyWrappingTDEA {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        System.out.println("\nTDEA KeyWrapping with Java version: " + Runtime.version());

        // testvector from TKW_AE.txt
        // testvectors: https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/mac/kwtestvectors.zip
        byte[] key = hexStringToByteArray("12b84c663120c196f8fc17428bc86a110d92cc7c4d3cb695");
        byte[] pt =  hexStringToByteArray("ef7da3da918d0679");
        byte[] ctExp =  hexStringToByteArray("7a72bbca3aa323aa1ac231ba");
        byte[] ct;
        Key dt;
        System.out.println("pt        : " + bytesToHex(pt));
        System.out.println("ctExpected: " + bytesToHex(ctExp));

        // jce
        SecretKeySpec keySpecJce = new SecretKeySpec(key, "TripleDES");
        Cipher tdesCipherJce = Cipher.getInstance("DESedeWrap");
        tdesCipherJce.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, keySpecJce);
        SecretKeySpec wrapkeySpecJce = new SecretKeySpec(pt, "DES");
        ct = tdesCipherJce.wrap(wrapkeySpecJce);
        System.out.println("ct JCE    : " + bytesToHex(ct));
        // unwrap for demonstration of a working implementation
        tdesCipherJce.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, keySpecJce);
        dt = tdesCipherJce.unwrap(ct, "DES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
        System.out.println("dt JCE    : " + bytesToHex(dt.getEncoded()));

        // jce 2
        SecretKeySpec keySpecJce2 = new SecretKeySpec(key, "TripleDES");
        Cipher tdesCipherJce2 = Cipher.getInstance("DESedeWrap");
        tdesCipherJce2.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, keySpecJce2);
        SecretKeySpec wrapkeySpecJce2 = new SecretKeySpec(pt, "DES");
        ct = tdesCipherJce2.wrap(wrapkeySpecJce2);
        System.out.println("ct JCE 2  : " + bytesToHex(ct));
        // unwrap for demonstration of a working implementation
        tdesCipherJce2.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, keySpecJce2);
        dt = tdesCipherJce2.unwrap(ct, "DES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
        System.out.println("dt JCE 2  : " + bytesToHex(dt.getEncoded()));

    }

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it me, or is the NIST document refer to different RFCs than the Java algorithm specification? The output is the wrong size as well.

Comment: @Maarten: I started my KeyWrapping-experience with AESWrap and all worked well out of the box with SunJce "AESWrap". 
Unfortunately I could not find any algorithm for TDEAWrap without a random initvector and with a ciphertext outputlength of (plaintextlength + 4 bytes) as shown in NIST testvectors. With Bouncy Castle there is a "DESEDERFC3211WRAP" algorithm available but there I got a ciphertext outputlength of (plaintextlength + 8). Any ideas for an NIST-conform algorithm?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I've not used the key wrap mechanism even once and I'm not in favor of them.  For AES I'd use AES-GCM-SIV, but that's not available for a 8 byte block cipher such as TDEA.

Comment: @Maarten: it's off topic - which library do you use for AES-GCM-SIV (I successfully run some tests with https://gitlab.com/tlchiu40209/easyaes-gcm-siv) ? Are there any plans to add AES-GCM-SIV to Bouncy Castle in the next future) ?

Comment: I *currently* don't. If Bouncy will support it is best asked on the bouncy castle dev mailing list. But to be honest, they would be much more appreciative if they would get a source submission.